# Change Cygwin Prompt

Tags: cygwin

The default cygwin prompt of `"user@computer path` *\n* `$"` is too long for me. I would like to keep the path.

I want it to become:

*path* $

Is there a config file I can modify to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change my terminal window prompt text?](https://superuser.com/questions/287669/is-it-possible-to-change-my-terminal-window-prompt-text)

Comment: [How to change the format of the bash prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/386404/44425)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `PS1` environment variable controls the prompt:

```
PS1='\w $ '
```

For more information on this and other prompt configuration topics, type `man bash` (assuming `bash` is your shell) and see the "PROMPTING" section.

To make this change permanent, edit your `~/.bashrc` file to add the above line.

Comment: ~/.bashrc does not get executed for a login shell. update ~/.bash_profile instead. I use the following prompt string, which has some other useful information, not just the path:
PS1='\[\e[32m\]\t \[\e[33m\]\w \[\e[31m\]\! \[\e[0m\]\$ '

Comment: Don't forget that normally .profile sources .bashrc, so that in effect, a login shell is initialized with the same stuff than a non-login shell _plus_ what's in .profile.
If that's the case, putting your new prompt in .bashrc kills two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 2):

A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option.
When  bash  is  invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading  that  file,  it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The  --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior
When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.

So it depends...i dont't use the --login, so i must add it to ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why having less context is better than having more...
The fact that there is a new line in the prompt means the length of the prompt should not be an issue, but try this:

```
PS1='\[\e[1;33m\]\w\n\[\e[1;36m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

or

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;33m\]\w\n\[\e[1;36m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

This gives you a coloured prompt:

```
/full/path/to/current/folder
$your command text here
```

That way, you always see your full folder context but still get a full line to input text. (I left out the customary space following the '$' because it's coloured for clarity).

```
Colours are:
    1. '/full/path/...' = yellow;
    2. '$' (on next line) = cyan;
    3. 'your command text...' = light grey.
```

For those who DO want the 'user@hostname ' context too:

```
PS1='\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[1;35m\]@\[\e[1;32m\]\h \[\e[1;33m\]\w\n\[\e[1;36m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

or

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[1;35m\]@\[\e[1;32m\]\h \[\e[1;33m\]\w\n\[\e[1;36m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

This gives you a coloured prompt:

```
user@hostname /full/path/to/current/folder
$your command text here
```

This is my preference.

```
Colours are:
    1. 'user' = (light) green;
    2. '@' = pink;
    3. 'hostname' = (light) green;
    4. '/full/path/...' = yellow;
    5. '$' (on next line) = cyan;
    6. 'your command text...' = light grey.
```

(No, there are no spelling mistakes in this post - Queen's English ;) )

Answer (score 1):

.bashrc didn't work for me. I added this to the end of /etc/profile and it worked:

```
export PS1="\[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\] \$ "
```

I'm using Cygwin version 2.11.2 (latest version as of 2018-12-18).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your ~/.bashrc. Gives a coloured prompt and keeps the status in a single line.

```
export PS1="\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ "
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally found that the other examples modified the prompt too much for my liking, so I found it more useful to determine where the current Cygwin prompt is set, what it looks like and then modify that as needed.

Turns out it's located in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and looks like this:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
```

I simply wanted to add a timestamp to my prompt to make it more practical, so I modified the above to add the current time to the very beginning in dark grey, and then added the string to my personal `~/.bashrc` file (located in `/home/<Username>/.bashrc`):

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[90m\]\t \[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\] \n\$ '
```

You can use a generator like [this](http://omar.io/ps1gen/) to help more visually learn the syntax of the PS1 prompt. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124407/what-color-codes-can-i-use-in-my-ps1-prompt) is a comprehensive list of all the colours you can make use of in the process.