# Ubuntu 12.04 - Terminal - Huge/Large text on each command line

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to change my terminal window prompt text?](https://superuser.com/questions/287669/is-it-possible-to-change-my-terminal-window-prompt-text)

I have been using "Ubuntu 12.04" for few days now (no previous Linux experiences at all) and I have noticed that the symbols on each command line more then this in many examples in the network.

For example, I have:

[image]

And I want to remove the "gotqn-System-Product-Name" part, because it is taking too much space?

What should I do to change this?

Comment: [Customizing Your Bash Command Prompt « Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/21/customizing-your-bash-command-prompt/)

Comment: @slhck Thank you - this solve my problem.

Comment: You're very welcome!