# How do I turn the dollar sign onto a new line in terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal, iterm2

In a terminal window I want to be able to enter commands on the next line

Instead of:

`Something-MacBook-Pro-2:~ someone$ <command>`

I want:

`Something-MacBook-Pro-2:~ someone
$ <command>`

It's shown in this video at 1:40 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zi-FIG3efag

It seems she is using iTerm2, but I can't find a way to change it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change my terminal window prompt text?](https://superuser.com/questions/287669/is-it-possible-to-change-my-terminal-window-prompt-text)

Comment: What you are looking for is the "prompt". You can modify it freely, but sometimes people just use presets like the ones that come from `oh-my-zsh` or more advanced ones like: https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt

Comment: If you are using `bash` (you don't say which shell you're using), then you can insert a new-line into your PS1 prompt string with `\n` (see the `PROMPTING` section of the `bash` manual. Other shells will have similar sequences which can be used.

Comment: @AFH That would be the answer :)

Comment: @Biswapriyo - I haven't elaborated it fully as an answer because there is no evidence of the questioner's research efforts: he ought to do at least some work towards arriving at his answer, which will make him much more likely to learn from the exercise.